# How do I remove this Rmarkdown output after the read_excel function?

Tags: r, r-markdown

How do I go about removing the output shown in the picture below after I use `read_excel` to import the data in r markdown. Basically I don't want there to be any output after this function. Please see attached image.

```
bdims <- read_excel("bdims.xlsx")

head(bdims)
```

[image: example of output]

Comment: Why are you using `r-markdown` and not `.R`?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `results = 'hide'`. So if eg. for standard rmarkdown. This will stop the output from showing. Read on the cheat sheet how to use other settings such as `echo` and `eval`

```
{results = 'hide'}
bdims <- read_excel("bdims.xlsx")
```

or with roxygen document for rendering rmarkdown,

```
#+ results = 'hide'
bdims <- read_excel("bdims.xlsx")
```

Comment: `eval = FALSE` *will stop the output from showing* because code won't be evaluated (run).

Comment: oops, that my bad, i was hasty! `results` would be more suited!